# Brute force bash scripting

Tags: shell-script

im a begginer at bash scripting, i was able to do a subdomain bruteforce but now im stuck at directory bruteforce, im using "curl" to do a get request and get a response (200,400,301) but im not able to make  it work

```
domain=$1
curl=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $domain/$dir)

while read dir;do
  $curl
  if [ $curl != 400 ];then
    echo "Dominios encontrados: " $domain/$dir
  fi
done < listadiretorios.txt
```

I know its too stupid but ive already looked for answers and did not find anything :)

Comment: Double-quote your variables when you use them - e.g. `"$domain/$dir"`.  URLs are especially likely to contain shell metacharacters (like `&`) that will affect the shell's operation.   See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).   Also, why are you setting variable $curl to be the output from a `curl` command, and then trying to execute the contents of that variable inside a `while read` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues I can see, a key problem is that you are executing the `curl` before the loop.

I think this should work better, without diverging too much from your original code.

Also you might need to look at more response codes.

```
domain="$1"

while read dir;do
  # capture response from curl command
  response="$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null "$domain/$dir")"
  # check curl response
  if [ "$response" != 400 ];then
    echo "Dominios encontrados: $domain/$dir"
  fi
done < listadiretorios.txt
```

Comment: Why do you not just call `curl` explicitly in the loop? You have "fancy" quotes (1st line), a dangling left-parentheses (3rd line), and missing quotes (the `eval`).

Comment: That's what I get for trying to write answers on my phone. And also trying to implement what the OP seemed to be attempting.  You're right, using `eval` is unnecessary here. Fixed.

Comment: Why you use `!=` which is for comparing strings?

Comment: I've just brought that across from what was in the original post.  It's no doing any particular harm, given that shell script isn't very opinionated about variable typing.

Comment: hi, i talked to a friend of mine yesterday and h e just helped me, anyways, thanks a lot guys, this is the new code btw:  

domain=$1
COR_RED="\e[31;1;4m"
COR_YELLOW="\e[33;1;1m"

  while read dir;do
    if wget $domain/$dir &> /dev/null;then
      echo -e ${COR_YELLOW}"Diretório encontrado: " ${COR_RED}"$1/$dir"
    fi
  done < listadiretorios.txt

Comment: thanks @bmx, u helped me a lot to get new views of clean code and good code as well, i really apreciate this!

Comment: No problem; it might be helpful for someone looking later if you add your final script as an answer.